# How to start a recording on the macOS built-in Voice Memo

Tags: voice-memo

The Voice Memo is not starting to record automatically.

[image]

If I press the red "Pause" button on the bottom left I end up back at the main screen.

[image]

Pressing the "Play" button does nothing. So how to use this (what should be dead simple) app?

Answer (score 1):

Go to system preferences and click on sound and then click on the input tab. You should see a panel like the one below.

[image]

Click on the Mac microphone and set the input volume to a resonable setting (I use about halfway across). You can choose a position such that speaking in a normal voice will move the input level about 1/3 up the blue scale. See below.

[image]

Now try recording using the method you tried previously. When you start the voice recorder and hit the red button you should get a screen like the one shown above. While running, the white line indicating sound intensity will be colored red.

Comment: Thx. I have it at full volume. Quicktime recordings are perfect: I am using that given this difficulty.

Comment: sorry my answer didn't solve your problems.  Have you tried reinstalling the app?